# html css behaves differently than it does in jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have the following jsfiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/gatorreina/0rcev6ux/5/ that behaves like I would like it to because it truncates the overflow of the first table in the column.

However, when I copy and paste the exact same code into my dancer2 template I get the following results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
-->

<!-- for controlling style of numberic sponsor amount field -->
<style>
body{ margin:1em; }
body *{ font-family:sans-serif }

input[type=number]{
    font-size:1em;
    width:8.5em;
    padding:3px;
    margin:0;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    font-size:1em;
    width:1.5em;
    padding:6px;
    margin:0;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
}



</style>

<!-- table { width: 100%; table-layout:fixed; }
table td { overflow: hidden; } -->

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var i;
    i=true;
    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
        if((!$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked'))&&($(this).find('input[type=number]').val()!="")&&($(this).find('input[type=number]').length)) {
            i=false;
        }
    });
    if (!i) 
    {
        alert("You must check the box if you want to sponsor this challenge!");
    }
    return i;
};
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form role="form" action="../../openchallenges" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <h4 class="text-center">Heading</h4>
        <div class="well" style="max-height: 300px;overflow: auto;">
          <ul class="list-group fancy-list-items">
            <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">

              <tr class="list-group-item">
                <td style="width:45px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">I want this column to truncate</td>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">This one is fine</td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Heading

```
I want this column to truncate  This one is fine
```

Any idea what could be the problem? I am using Firefox.

Comment: It's a bit vague. Can you check the developer tools of your browser, target the `td`, and make sure some styles aren't interfering?

Comment: What browser?  It worked ok for me in MS Edge

Comment: Firefox. Not sure how to target the td in developer tools. But it is the exact same css and html that is in the jsfiddle so I am not clear on how there could be styles missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried commenting out the `<link  rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">` it works -- the column would truncate. However, I need bootstrap.min.css so I uncommented it and tried:

```
.PLRSNAME-col {
    /*width: 100%;
    min-width: 1px;*/
    max-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}



<td class="PLRSNAME-col">I want this column to truncate</td>
```

And it now works -- the column truncates.